# group regex pattern matching of a string in php "preg_match"

Tags: php, regex

I have a string

(A) fdkf djkf gsdfjkg hsfl (B) jfg dkfjg hdksfjg dkfj (c) ndfkj gndfg ndfn  (d) kdjfskdj fs;s dknls

Desired output shuld be like this

```
4 group matched
(A) fdkf djkf gsdfjkg hsfl
(B) jfg dkfjg hdksfjg dkfj
(c) ndfkj gndfg ndfn
(d) kdjfskdj fs;s dknls
```

Please help

I am trying `/((.+?) (?=\())/` regex but it is not creating 4 groups

I am trying here to create this pattern
https://regex101.com/r/KxAcaV/1

```
$re = '/((.+?) (?=\())/';
$str = '(A) fdkf djkf gsdfjkg hsfl (B) jfg dkfjg hdksfjg dkfj (c) ndfkj gndfg ndfn  (d) kdjfskdj fs;s dknls';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Hi @JayBlanchard I changed the quesion that what I am trying ans what problem I am facing.

Comment: You will not get upvotes by asking for them (your comment on @Alex's answer). In fact, your request may have prompted the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string always has 4 groups, then you can use a [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/KxAcaV/3) matching a symbol in parenthesis followed by some text repated 4 times:

```
^(\(.\).+?)\s+(\(.\).+?)\s+(\(.\).+?)\s+(\(.\).+?)$
```

But if your string has a variable number of groups, then you can't get them all inside different matched groups, you'll need to get them with `preg_match_all`:

```
(\(.\)[^(]+)
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/KxAcaV/2).

Comment: Thanks ALex its working for me. and if this question is really good then please upvote for the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all):

```
$str = '(A) fdkf djkf gsdfjkg hsfl (B) jfg dkfjg hdksfjg dkfj (c) ndfkj gndfg ndfn (d) kdjfskdj fs;s dknls';

preg_match_all('/\(.+?\).+?(?= \(|$)/', $str, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => (A) fdkf djkf gsdfjkg hsfl
    [1] => (B) jfg dkfjg hdksfjg dkfj
    [2] => (c) ndfkj gndfg ndfn
    [3] => (d) kdjfskdj fs;s dknls
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to split your string with the regex

```
(?i) +(?=\([a-z]\))
```

which matches one or more spaces followed by a left parenthesis followed by a letter followed by a right parenthesis, `(?=\([a-z]\))` being a *positive lookahead*.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/KxAcaV/5)